# Buttons In Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to create a screen in which there is an image in the background and in the foreground there are two centered buttons.
When either of the buttons are clicked, I want to display new screens.

I am able to create the buttons only -- the rest I am unable to complete.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Feel free to post some code samples.) Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Which BB OS are you targeting?  I ask because it's easier to create backgrounds with 4.6 and up.  Also, do you know how to add a listener to the buttons or just create them?

Answer (score 2):

RIM offers an extensive set of [Development Guides](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=Development+Guides) that are a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a field manager to cover the entire screen. and in the paint method of that manager you need to draw the background image of entire screen size then call `super.Paint()`

after that you can add two buttons on the same manager.

```
final Bitmap bodyBG = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("body"+ApplicationUtil.getInstance().getScreenResolution()+".png");
 VerticalFieldManager pannel = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL){


protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

setExtent(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

graphics.clear();

graphics.drawBitmap(0,0,bodyBG.getWidth(), bodyBG.getHeight(), bodyBG, 0, 0);

super.paint(graphics);

}

};
```

now add buttons on pannel